# Xamarin Forms custom control: implement a method in the renderer

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, interface

I'm trying to create an extended version of the standard XF Map object:

```
public class RRMap: Map
{

    public void DoSomethingOnMap() {
        /* ... */
    }

}
```

I also created an Android renderer (iOS will come later):

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(RRMap), typeof(RRMapRendererAndroid))]
namespace MyApp.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class RRMapRendererAndroid : MapRenderer
    {
        public RRMapRendererAndroid(Context context) : base(context) { }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.GetMapAsync(this);
            }
        }

        protected override MarkerOptions CreateMarker(Pin pin)
        {
            var marker = new MarkerOptions();
            marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude));
            marker.SetTitle(pin.Label);
            marker.SetSnippet(pin.Address);
            marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.DefaultMarker(210));
            return marker;
        }

    }
}
```

Everything is working fine so far: the map is rendered and pins are created with a custom color.

Unfortunately, I'm stuck on the implementation of `DoSomethingOnMap` method: it should be a method in the shared code, but it should be implemented in different ways, depending on the platform.

In other circumstances, I would create an interface using DependencyService for implementation, but in this particular case I can't figure out how to proceed.

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: Hi, I tried the event approach, it works fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **first** solution is you can use a [messaging-center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center), this can communicate between shared project and iOS/Android project.

Publish a message in the `doSomethingOnMap` method and anywhere you subscribed to the message will be triggered.

The **second** is create an event in your shared project and subscribe to that event in the renderer, I wrote both two solutions below:

In your shared project:

```
public class CustomMap : Map
{
    public List<CustomPin> CustomPins { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler CallToNativeMethod;

    public void doSomething()
    {
        if (CallToNativeMethod != null)
            CallToNativeMethod(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    public void doSomething(CustomMap myMap) {


        MessagingCenter.Send<CustomMap>(this, "Hi");

    }
}
```

In the renderer:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {

        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<CustomMap>(this, "Hi", (sender) =>
            {
                // Do something whenever the "Hi" message is received
                Console.WriteLine("hi");
            });

            ((CustomMap)e.NewElement).CallToNativeMethod += (sender, arg) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("native method");
            };
        }
    }
```

At anywhere you want to call this method:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    customMap.doSomething();
    customMap.doSomething(customMap);
}
```