# Xamarin Forms - calling a shared code method from the platform project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have read the two other questions on SO regarding this and I wanted to know if there is a good solution for that now / best practice.

Long story short, we use an SDK which is written natively and we've wrapped it so that it works on Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS. It has asynchronous callback methods. I need to call a method in the shared code when a callback is received in the Android project for instance.

There's a lot of info for doing the opposite - using `DependencyService`. How about in my scenario? Does anyone have experience with an app like this and what's the best approach to keep code clean and do this using MVVM?

The options I know are:

- Using a static App instance - this is what we currently do.
- `MessagingCenter`
- Anything else?

Actually I've never seen anyone recommend usage of `MessagingCenter` for anything else than communication between ViewModels so I am not sure it is recommended here. Also, I need to know the sender object type so I need a reference to the class in the platform specific project.

Comment: I would recommend you to use messagingCenter to pass data or call method between shared project and platform project. You can just send a new object instead of the class in the platform specific project. Also, have a look at using eventhandler as I mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58223899/xamarin-forms-custom-control-implement-a-method-in-the-renderer/58229132#58229132) may help.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I am not sure the handler answer applies to my case because I don't want to call from the shared project into the platform specific one, i need the opposite. So, when the SDK callback is received in Android/iOS, I need to call a method in the Shared project - show a page for example. So to use MessagingCenter, in the Shared project I would subscribe to the event only by providing the type of the source - so I need to have the type shared in both. I guess it's best to put that type in a .NET standard library so that I can subscribe to messages from that source.

Comment: Yes, you can have a try with MessagingCenter and I think it's the best choice.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Thank you Jack! Last thing and you can provide your comment as an answer so that I choose it. In this forum (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/70235/xamarin-forms-messagingcenter-between-two-differents-pages-projects) they discuss using `App`as a source object. Is this fine? And even if it is, I assume it's better to have an object specifically for that purpose, say "EventMessanger"? Or that would be purely for code clarity? I also hope having 10 different message types is fine with MessagingCenter... Thanks you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use [messagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to pass data or call method between shared project and platform project. You can just send a new object instead of the class in the platform specific project.

Also, have a look at using eventhandler as I mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58223899/xamarin-forms-custom-control-implement-a-method-in-the-renderer/58229132#58229132) may help someone who want to call from the shared project into the platform specific one.

BTW, I mean you can even pass an object as `TSender` if it is not necessary to use:

```
    MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(new object(), "Hi");

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object>(new object(), "Hi", (sender) =>
    {
        // Do something whenever the "Hi" message is received
    });
```

Comment: Oh you mean really just an `Object`! Got it. I assume this would not allow me to listen to any specific type of object once I have a subscribe like this as it would pick up all messages. So if I write another Subscribe<Item> it will never hit as Item is already an object..?

Comment: No, it will hit, object is object, item is item, they are different.